# How to edit the schema identity type via twig?

Tags: plugin-seomatic

I have a Channel type Section and I set the identity type as an **Article** in SEOmatic Main Entity of Page (JSON-LD). We are now planning to create entries in that section with different entity type (**NewsArticle**). I would like to ask how can I manually edit the type to **NewsArticle** in JSON-LD via twig or is there any best way?

The other option I think is, to disable the JSON-LD for that section and manually create but I also don't know how to disable the JSON-LD for the specific section.